# Error Call to a member function delay() on null when call in $user->notify($natifictionclass)->delay()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, task-queue

Call to a member function delay() on null

I am getting above when i am calling notify method with dealy.

Notication class i am geting.in job table data is store but  i am getting  error in call to member function delay on null. can one  help me in that.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Model
{
    //
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'user';
    /**
     .....
}
```

notification class

```
    namespace App\Notifications;

    use App\Channels\PushChannel;
    use App\Channels\SmsChannel;
    use App\Libraries\Helper;
    use App\Waitlists;

    use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

    class WaitingPrecall extends Notification implements  ShouldBroadcast
    {

    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $message;
    public $phone;


    public $deviceGuests;

    public function _construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return $this->sendtype==1?[PushChannel::class]: [PushChannel::class,SmsChannel::class];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */

    public function toSms($notifiable)
    {
         $data=Helper::send_message($this->smstext,$this->phone);

         return $data;
    }
}
```

function call for

```
$waitPreCall=new WaitingPrecall();

....
....

$guest=User::find($waitDataNew->user->gust_id);

 $guest->notify($waitPreCall)->delay($when);//here i am getting error
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941191/call-to-a-member-function-delay-on-null-on-laravel-notification

Answer (score 0):

`$guest->notify($waitPreCall)` is returning null, that's why you're getting an error. Check the definition of `notify()` to see what is happening.

Comment: But is laravel function

Comment: Sure it is, and you have the source code plus a hint where to look

Comment: yes, i am following step which give in laravel site.so why i am getting error.