# Call to a member function delay() on null on laravel notification

Tags: laravel, notifications

Hi i got this error message "Call to a member function delay() on null"

this is my code in contoller

```
$input  = $request->end_date;
$format = 'd/m/Y';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $input)->toDateString();
$when = Carbon::parse($date)->subDays(7);
$this->dispatch(
   $request->user()->notify(new EndDate($asset))->delay($when)
);
```

I have no idea how to fix that, I'm new in programming, so I hope someone could help me to fix this error.

Comment: Try viewing the data for `$request->user()->notify()` by doing `dd($$request->user()->notify(new EndDate($asset))`. May be it gives you `null`.

Comment: `notify` returns `void`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were close!

The delay method should be called on the `EndDate` notification and not chained on after the `notify()` method.

Also, you shouldn't need to use `$this->dispatch()` as the `notify()` method will do this for you.

```
$request->user()->notify((new EndDate($asset))->delay($when));
```

Below is the exact same code, however, I've just broken it on to multiple lines to make it clearer and easier to see:

```
$request->user()->notify(
    (new EndDate($asset))->delay($when)
);
```

Comment: thanks, it's not returns any error. but, why the notification is sent? 
I want to sent it in other day, but it sent now